# If iframe contains this class display div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to display [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xbseur7z/) the div with class `is-dynamic` only if the iframe contains this message: "Keine Angebote zu «kaufen» gefunden". How can I achieve that?

I have tried using this without any results

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var iframe = $('#frame-8be8f6c4-b1a0-8aaa-7011-ccfe2f33bf4b').text();
    console.log(iframe);
        if(iframe == 'Keine Angebote zu «kaufen» gefunden'){
        $('.is-dynamic').show();
    } else {
        $('.is-dynamic').hide();
    }
});
```

I saw that that message in the iframe is included into a div with class `flashmessage info`

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't access a cross origin iframe due to browser security restrictions - *unless you control the code in both pages*

Comment: The iframe url allows CORS so you can fetch the html: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/oasb0gmn/